# How to accelerate car based off of Animation Curve?

Tags: unity, c#, physics

I am making a karting game and I want the karts velocity to accelerate based off a curve. This would allow me to quickly iterate different types of cars that accelerate in different ways. I was inspired by this GDC talk: https://youtu.be/Db1AgGavL8E?t=1446 (link goes to spot I'm talking about) right now I'm having trouble getting the cars to move at all. So far I have created a curve that increases 0-1 over 5 secs. This is meant to be its relative velocity over time. I then have a curve which is the inverse of that using this method:

```
inverseSpeedCurve = new AnimationCurve();
        for (int i = 0; i < SpeedCurve.length; i++)
        {
            Keyframe inverseKey = new Keyframe(SpeedCurve.keys[i].value, SpeedCurve.keys[i].time);
            inverseSpeedCurve.AddKey(inverseKey);
        }
```

I use the inverse curve to find the time at a specified speed. That way if the player lets off the pedal and decelerates a bit it would reaccelerate at the new speed.

Finally this is how I move the car:

```
//Inside fixed Update I want vehicle to follow velocity curve
        float forwardInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float speedTime = inverseSpeedCurve.Evaluate(rb.velocity.magnitude); // give us time at speed
        float speed = SpeedCurve.Evaluate(speedTime + Time.deltaTime); // give us new speed at new time
        
        
        Debug.Log("Time: "+ speedTime + "New speed: " + speed);
        Debug.Log(rb.velocity.magnitude);
        rb.AddForce(speed * TopSpeed *transform.forward * forwardInput,ForceMode.Acceleration);
```

I have experimented with different ways of moving the car but none of them have worked It either goes way too fast or doesn't move at all.